# App freezes while trying to scroll to bottom ios tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uiscrollview

I need to scroll to bottom in tableview with many rows without freeze.

I have talbeview with infinity scroll (when user scrolls down, app makes request and fetches new part of data). When i'm trying to scroll to bottom by settig table's content offset or by scrollToRow, app freezes and i see cpu usage 100%, and ram up to 100mb (in normal state it is only 10mb).

I guess this is because of cell rendering. I was trying to set async rendering, or rendering with queue, but nothing.

This problem is seems like [Scrolling bottom in tableview and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383408/scrolling-bottom-in-tableview-and-performance) but there is no answer.

Comment: Post some relevant code, it is not possible to help otherwise. Also, once your app is stuck you can stop it in debugger and see what part of code it is running at that moment

Comment: You're scrolling to the bottom of a list with infinite rows, and are wondering why it's freezing?